# Function with jquery.alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

I want to implement `jquery.alphanumeric` in HTML pattern, so I used a jQuery plugin from [here](https://github.com/johnantoni/jquery.alphanumeric). Can this be shortened or improved?

```
<input type="text" char-allow="$#*" class="alpha">
<input type="text" char-allow="+-" class="numeric">
<input type="text" char-allow="&" class="alphanumeric">

<script>
    function setAlphaNumeric(){
        $(".numeric").each(function(){
            var a = $(this).attr("char-allow"); $(this).numeric({allow:a});
        });
        $(".alpha").each(function(){
            var a = $(this).attr("char-allow"); $(this).alpha({allow:a});
        });
        $(".alphanumeric").each(function(){
            var a = $(this).attr("char-allow"); $(this).alphanumeric({allow:a});
        });
    }

$(function(){

setAlphaNumeric();

});
</script>
```

Comment: Apart from suggestions in below answers, I'll suggest **1.** Use `data-*` custom attributes **2.** Use `pattern` attribute. Ex for alpha `<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z$#*]+" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be shortened to:

```
function setAlphaNumeric() {
  $(".numeric, .alpha, .alphanumeric").each(function() {
    $(this)[this.className]({
      allow: $(this).attr("char-allow")
    });
  });
}

$(setAlphaNumeric);
```